# How i can show default 100 entries per page with Simple-Datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

By default 10 entries are displayed per page. But, I am trying to display 100 entries per page in Simple Data Table.

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    // Simple-DataTables
    // https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki

    const datatablesSimple = document.getElementById('datatablesSimple');
    if (datatablesSimple) {
        new simpleDatatables.DataTable(datatablesSimple);

       
    }
});
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Datatables https://datatables.net/

Comment: As described in the documentation, use [`perPage`](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki/perPage).

Comment: `let dataTable = new DataTable("#myTable", { perPage: 100 });`

Answer (score 1):

here is the link somebody has already answered.

[How to change results per page value in datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871705/how-to-change-results-per-page-value-in-datatables)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({
      "iDisplayLength": 100
   });
})
```

Or as @andrewjames commented

```
let dataTable = new DataTable("#myTable", { perPage: 100 });
```

Comment: The question is not about [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It is about [Simple-DataTables](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    // Simple-DataTables
    // https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki

    const datatablesSimple = document.getElementById('datatablesSimple');
    if (datatablesSimple) {
        new simpleDatatables.DataTable(datatablesSimple, {
         perPage: 100
         });

       
    }
});
```